# Trying to install 64-bit Ubuntu in VB, says it says it needs x86-64 CPU, but my CPU is 64-bit

Tags: virtualbox

When installing Ubuntu on my VB I am not able to choose 64-bit because the option is not showing up and yet my laptop runs on a 64-bit CPU. The system is not booting and it keeps on telling me

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what OS you have installed on the laptop. If it's Windows, make sure you do not have Hyper-v running.

If another hypervisor is running on your system then VirtualBox won't be able utilise your CPU virtualisation capabilities.

I'd also check to make sure that your CPU has Intel VT-x/AMD-V enabled: [Windows](https://www.shaileshjha.com/how-to-find-out-if-intel-vt-x-or-amd-v-virtualization-technology-is-supported-in-windows-10-windows-8-windows-vista-or-windows-7-machine/), [Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/567208/how-to-detect-if-vt-x-has-been-turned-on-in-the-bios)